# A way to automatically pass parameters to a function?

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I have a bunch of callback functions in a module. They all call `some_func()` with the first, say, couple of arguments always the same and derived from their own arguments, while other arguments vary. Like so:

```py
from outer.space import some_func
def callback_A(param1, param2, param3):
    ...
    some_func(param2+param1, param3, ..., ...)
    ...

def callback_B(param1, param2, param3, param4):
    ...
    some_func(param2+param1, param3, ..., ...)
    ...
```

And it's all over the code. And uglier than just param2+param1.

In C/C++, I'd just do a macro

```
#define    S_F(a,b)    some_func(param2+param1, param3, a, b)
```

and start using S_F inside callbacks instead of `some_func`. What can I do in Python?

Comment: I'll pull things from my replies so far up here so it's all in one place: I can't change the definition of `some_func`. The problem seems to be this: if things are to be helped in one sweep, it must be done *outside* the callback functions, but param1, etc, only become visible *inside*. The C preprocessor does this by being stupid: it doesn't care what param2+param1 is, it's just text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `functools.partial`

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def my_function(a,b,c,d,e):
...     print (a,b,c,d,e)
... 
>>> func_with_defaults = partial(my_function, 1, 2, e=5)
>>> func_with_defaults(3, 4)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Edit:

Since you do not have these values in advance you can't use `partial` or `lambda`.
You may be tempted to do this:

```
>>> A = lambda x: x + y
>>> def do_something(y):
...     return A(2)    # hope it uses the `y` parameter...
... 
>>> do_something(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in do_something
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: global name 'y' is not defined
```

But as can you see it does not work. Why? Because when you define a function python saves the scope in which you defined it and uses it to resolve the `global`/`nonlocal` variables.

If you had access to `some_func` it would be possible to do what you want by "hacking" the interpreter stack using `inspect` but this is not a robust nor elegant thing to do, so do *not* do that.

What I'd do in your case is to simply rewrite the statement.

If you really want to avoid this, you can try something using `exec`:

```
>>> def some_function(a,b,c):
...     print(a,b,c)
... 
>>> code = 'some_function(a+b,c,%s)'
>>> 
>>> def func_one(a,b, c):
...     exec code % 1
... 
>>> def func_two(a,b,c):
...     exec code % 2
... 
>>> func_one(1,2,3)
(3, 3, 1)
>>> func_two(1,2,3)
(3, 3, 2)
```

But this is *ugly*.

If you use only positional arguments to your function you may do something more elegant such as:

```
>>> def compute_values(a,b,c):
...     return (a+b, c)
... 
>>> def func_one(a,b,c):
...     some_function(*(compute_values(a,b,c) + (1,)))
... 
>>> def func_two(a,b,c):
...     some_function(*(compute_values(a,b,c) + (2,)))
... 
>>> func_one(1,2,3)
(3, 3, 1)
>>> func_two(1,2,3)
(3, 3, 2)
```

But at this point you are just repeating a different text, and you lost much readability.
If you want to have preprocessing features in python you may try [Python Preprocessing](http://code.google.com/p/pypp/), even though, in your case, I'd rather just repeat the function calls.

Comment: I don't know the values which I can substitute in `partial` beforehand: param1, etc, are parameters to callbacks, not 1,2, or 5. Doing `partial` inside each callback where param1, etc, become visible defeats the whole DRY attempt.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Now I understood what you want exactly. No there is no way to do that. At least not in a clean, elegant and robust way, since python does not have a preprocessor. Depending on the exact signature there may be some methods that could be used but I think it's more simple to just copy-paste the call. Anyway I think that also in C it's a ugly hack, since the macro does not make clear that it uses some hidden parameter that ought to be in the scope with the correct type.

Answer (score 3):

You could base it on decorators:

```
import functools
from outer.space import some_func

def with_some(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(param1, param2, param3, *args):
        new_args = f(*args)
        return some_func(param1+param2, param3, *new_args)

    return wrapper

@with_some
def callback_A():
    return ()  # Will call some_func(param1 + param2, param3)

...

@with_some
def callback_B(param4):
    return param4,  # some_func(param1 + param2, param3, param4)
```

The wrapped functions will all have signature `f(param1, param2, param3, *args)`

Answer (score 1):

Simplely you can just use `globals()/locals()` to automatically get the context variables.

But if your functions saved in different files, then you can try `inspect` module to access caller's variables.

```
import inspect

def f1():
    v=11111
    f2()

def f2():
    v = inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals['v']
    print(v)

f1() # print 11111
```

Here is another similar question:
[Access variables of caller function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608987/access-variables-of-caller-function-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
S_F = lambda a, b: some_func(param2+params1, param3, a, b)
```

Keep in mind that `param1`, `param2` and `param3` must be available in the scope of the lambda statement, just as `some_func`.

Comment: Does "param_i must be available in the scope of the lambda" mean that I have to declare it inside every callbackA, callbackB, ...? Is there no way to do this at module scope?

Answer (score 0):

How about with [keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) instead of positional arguments in the function signature:

```
some_func(**kwargs):
    Instead of position arguments, just use the keys that some_func can respond to. 
    You can defaults to the ones not included...
    if key1 in kwargs:
        #use key1...
    #...

def callback_A(param1, param2, param3):
    some_func(key1=param1+parma2,key2=param3, other_key=...)


def callback_B(param1, param2, param3, param4):
     some_func(key1=param2+param1, key2=param3, other_keys=..., ...)
```

---

*Edit*

If you cannot change the function signature to `some_func` then you can wrap it:

```
def some_func(a,b,c,d,e):
    print 'some_funct({}, {}, {}, {}, {})'.format(a,b,c,d,e)

def some_func_wrap(**kwargs):
    params={'p1':'default a','p2':'default b',
              'p3':'default c','p4':'default d','p5':'default e'}
    for p,arg in kwargs.items():
        try:
            del params[p]   # to raise an error if bad key
            params[p]=arg
        except KeyError:
            print 'bad param to some_func_wrap()\n'
            raise

    some_func(*[params[k] for k in sorted(params.keys())])

some_func_wrap(p1=1,p2=1+3)
```

prints: `some_funct(1, 4, default c, default d, default e)`

Comment: I'm not at a liberty to modify `outer.space`, in particular `some_func`. It only has positional arguments. The problem is not omitting arguments, quite the opposite: I'm trying to pass them on, just *silently*.

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov: You can wrap `some_func` (which is equivalent to a C macro...) or use a function decorator then...