# How can I access variables from the caller, even if it isn't an enclosing scope (i.e., implement dynamic scoping)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider this example:

```
def outer():
    s_outer = "outer\n"

    def inner():
        s_inner = "inner\n"
        do_something()

    inner()
```

I want the code in `do_something` to be able to access the variables of the calling functions further up the call stack, in this case `s_outer` and `s_inner`. More generally, I want to call it from various other functions, but always execute it in their respective context and access their respective scopes (implement *dynamic scoping*).

I know that in Python 3.x, the [`nonlocal` keyword allows access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/) to `s_outer` from within `inner`. Unfortunately, that only helps with `do_something` if it's defined within `inner`. Otherwise, `inner` isn't a *lexically* enclosing scope (similarly, neither is `outer`, unless `do_something` is defined within `outer`).

I figured out how to inspect stack frames with the standard library `inspect`, and made a small accessor that I can call from within `do_something()` like this:

```
def reach(name):
    for f in inspect.stack():
        if name in f[0].f_locals:
            return f[0].f_locals[name]
    return None
```

and then

```
def do_something():
    print( reach("s_outer"), reach("s_inner") )
```

works just fine.

Can `reach` be implemented more simply? How else can I solve the problem?

Comment: Is walking the stack really correct? You want to walk Python scopes (from nested functions out to the module), not call stack frames. In your example above they are the same because you are calling `inner` inside of `outer`, but imagine that you would return `inner` instead and then do something like `outer()()`. Would your approach still work?

Comment: @Mitar no; `nonlocal` already walks through enclosing scopes. The goal is to *treat the caller* as though it were an enclosing scope (dynamic scope) *even though it isn't* in Python (which implements lexical scope, like almost all modern languages). OP walks the stack because the stack is what tells you who the callers are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I ended up doing was

```
scope = locals()
```

and make `scope` accessible from `do_something`.  That way I don't have to reach, but I can still access the dictionary of local variables of the caller.  This is quite similar to building a dictionary myself and passing it on.

Comment: "make accessible" how, if not by passing it?

Answer (score 9):

There is no and, in my opinion, should be no elegant way of implementing `reach` since that introduces a new non-standard indirection which is really hard to comprehend, debug, test and maintain. As the Python mantra (try `import this`) says:

> Explicit is better than implicit.

So, just pass the arguments.  You-from-the-future will be really grateful to you-from-today.

Comment: I was worried that that's the answer.  Ah well.  Independently of what the reach() function does, is there a more compact way to implement the nested for/if at all?

Comment: @Jens Can't come up with anything that would be more readable. You could check if traversing through `f_back` from `inspect.currentframe()` looks better to you.

Answer (score 7):

We can get naughtier.

This is an answer to the "Is there a more elegant/shortened way to implement the `reach()` function?" half of the question.

1. We can give better syntax for the user: instead of `reach("foo")`, `outer.foo`.

   This is nicer to type, and the language itself immediately tells you if you used a name that can't be a valid variable (attribute names and variable names have the same constraints).
2. We can raise an error, to properly distinguish "this doesn't exist" from "this was set to `None`".

   If we actually want to smudge those cases together, we can `getattr` with the default parameter, or `try`-`except AttributeError`.
3. We can optimize: no need to pessimistically build a list big enough for all the frames at once.

   In most cases we probably won't need to go all the way to the root of the call stack.
4. Just because we're inappropriately reaching up stack frames, violating one of the most important rules of programming to not have things far away invisibly effecting behavior, doesn't mean we can't be civilized.

   If someone is trying to use this Serious API for Real Work on a Python without stack frame inspection support, we should helpfully let them know.

```py
import inspect


class OuterScopeGetter(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        if frame is None:
            raise RuntimeError('cannot inspect stack frames')
        sentinel = object()
        frame = frame.f_back
        while frame is not None:
            value = frame.f_locals.get(name, sentinel)
            if value is not sentinel:
                return value
            frame = frame.f_back
        raise AttributeError(repr(name) + ' not found in any outer scope')


outer = OuterScopeGetter()
```

Excellent. Now we can just do:

```py
>>> def f():
...    return outer.x
... 
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
AttributeError: 'x' not found in any outer scope
>>> 
>>> x = 1
>>> f()
1
>>> x = 2
>>> f()
2
>>> 
>>> def do_something():
...     print(outer.y)
...     print(outer.z)
... 
>>> def g():
...     y = 3
...     def h():
...         z = 4
...         do_something()
...     h()
... 
>>> g()
3
4
```

Perversion elegantly achieved.

(P.S. This is a simplified read-only version of a more complete implementation in my [`dynamicscope`](https://pypi.org/project/dynamicscope/) library.)

Comment: @Jens yeah I've been thinking about learning the new packaging ways for a while, but it seems like if I just did a basic straightforward `setuptools`-based `pyproject.toml` it would be a regression for a lot of my backwards-compatibility stuff... for this toy `dynamicscope` package the benefit is minimal (just `distutils` support) so it's a good candidate to switch over, but for example look at how my [`compose`](https://pypi.org/project/compose) module's  [`setup.py`](https://github.com/mentalisttraceur/python-compose/blob/main/setup.py) picks different source depending on version.

Comment: True, if you’d like to support Python 2.7 and older Python 3.x versions then it gets hairy. The bane of backwards compatibility…

Comment: Of course, The Ideal Way for me to solve all my backwards-compatibility cares would be to find or write a backpiler that takes the latest Python source and transpiles it to older backwards-compatible Python source, then to find or write a way to hook that into a build system configured through `pyproject.toml`... and also make that build system generate sdists with whatever portability characteristics I'm looking for... the beauty of the modern packaging direction is that we should be able to hook that into `pyproject.toml` - I just haven't yet had the time to figure out *how* exactly.

Comment: @Jens that's a great template repo by the way - I think it will help me get familiar with some of what I want to learn and some things that I'd probably like to eventually use in my projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a better way to solve this problem? (Other than wrapping the respective data into dicts and pass these dicts explicitly to do_something())

Passing the dicts explicitly is a better way.

What you're proposing sounds very unconventional. When code increases in size, you have to break down the code into a modular architecture, with clean APIs between modules. It also has to be something that is easy to comprehend, easy to explain, and easy to hand over to another programmer to modify/improve/debug it. What you're proposing sounds like it is *not* a clean API, unconventional, with a non-obvious data flow. I suspect it would probably make many programmers grumpy when they saw it. :)

Another option would be to make the functions members of a class, with the data being in the class instance. That could work well if your problem can be modelled as several functions operating on the data object.

Comment: Everything you say makes sense to me, and usually I'd agree.  Unusually though, I'm learning Python at the moment and that means I want to get as low down and dirty as possible.  It's not shipping code and just for a private project, so I'll be the only grumpy programmer here ;-)