# Scope error working with imported module in Python 3

Tags: python, scope, syntax-error, python-import, python-nonlocal

I have an imported function from a separate file I have previously created.
In it I declare the variable `nums` to be `nonlocal` and then work with it. So with that context I will give you a snippet of my code and my error.

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(cwd + "/myfunctions"))

from opening_questions import opening_questions

def runing_app():

    nums = []

    opening_questions()

    def core_app(jpm):... # this is what I am trying to execute from all this.

    for jpm in nums:
        core_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=core_app, args=(jpm,))
        core_process.start()
        print('RAN')
        break
runing_app()
```

In `opening_questions()` I declare `nonlocal nums`
and try to work with `nums` inside my function.
This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/gdfelt/Python projects/test versions/test(current work)/testX.py", line 22, in <module>
    from opening_questions import opening_questions
File "/home/gdfelt/Python projects/test versions/test(current work)/myfunctions/opening_questions.py", line 19
    nonlocal nums
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'nums' found
```

This code ran just fine before I ran it from a separate file. **What do I need to have this code work?**  I'm using python 3.5 -- if you need clarification, please ask.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access variables of caller function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608987/access-variables-of-caller-function-in-python)

Comment: "This code ran just fine before I ran it from a separate file." This could only be the case if `opening_nums` were **defined inside** `runing_app`. A calling function is **not** an enclosing scope.

Comment: See also: [What is lexical scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454)

Answer (score 0):

For me, this comes down to the issue that this works:

```
def runing_app():
    def opening_questions():
        nonlocal nums
        nums += " World!"

    nums = "Hello"
    opening_questions()
    print(nums)

runing_app()
```

But this doesn't:

```
def opening_questions():
    nonlocal nums
    nums += " World!"

def runing_app():
    nums = "Hello"
    opening_questions()
    print(nums)

runing_app()
```

Regardless of whether we're changing, or just looking at, `nums`, we get the message:

> SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'nums' found"

Which is explained by `help('nonlocal')`:

> Names listed in a "nonlocal" statement, unlike those listed in a
>   "global" statement, must refer to ***pre-existing bindings*** in an
>   ***enclosing scope*** (the scope in which a new binding should be created
>   ***cannot be determined unambiguously***).

(My emphasis.)  In the code that doesn't work, the binding of `nums` is ambiguous as we don't know who might call `opening_questions()` at runtime (caller may not define `nums`).  And the binding is not found in the enclosing scope (text).

This would ***not*** be the case for `global`, as no matter who calls `opening_questions()`, we look in the ***same*** place for for a global.

The confusion may come about from dynamic scope languages that first look locally, then up the call stack, and finally globally.  In Python there are three non-overlapping options: look locally; look at the enclosing scope; look globally. There's no combining them nor looking up the call stack.